# Extract data from a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, extract

I have a file in the below format. Need to extract some data

```
depth=3 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = abc.xyz.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = abc.xyz.com
   i:C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep 13 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 11 23:59:59 2023 GMT
 1 s:C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
   i:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Oct 22 00:00:00 2015 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 19 00:00:00 2025 GMT
 2 s:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: May 25 12:00:00 2015 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 01:00:00 2037 GMT
 3 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep  2 00:00:00 2009 GMT; NotAfter: Jun 28 17:39:16 2034 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

From the Certificate chain section, I need to extract all lines containing s:, i: and v: to a new file.

I tried with the following

```
Get-Content "input.txt" | Select-String -pattern '(s:.*)|(i:.*)|(v:.*)' | Out-File "output.txt"
```

and I get the below extract in the output file

```
 0 s:CN = abc.xyz.com
   i:C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
   v:NotBefore: Sep 13 00:00:00 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 11 23:59:59 2023 GMT
 1 s:C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
   i:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
   v:NotBefore: Oct 22 00:00:00 2015 GMT; NotAfter: Oct 19 00:00:00 2025 GMT
 2 s:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - 
G2
   v:NotBefore: May 25 12:00:00 2015 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 01:00:00 2037 GMT
 3 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - 
G2
   i:C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
   v:NotBefore: Sep  2 00:00:00 2009 GMT; NotAfter: Jun 28 17:39:16 2034 GMT
```

Everything is as expected, but the text G2 always gets extracted on a new line rather than being in continuation of the previous line. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: It might be some configuration with your text editor. Try to open in other editors. Also, check whether there is new line character in output file before G2, G3.

Comment: It is working fine for me. may be you have got wordwrap and text editor half open

Comment: I checked that already. Text wrap is off. I tried opening the text file in notepad and also notepad++. G2 is on the next line itself. I am confused

Comment: I have tried several iterations of it. I am still getting the same output. Can someone help here please.